# __asm__ gcc call to a memory address

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have a code that allocates memory, copies some buffer to that allocated memory and then it jumps to that memory address.

the problem is that I cant jump to the memory address. Im using gcc and `__asm__` but I cant call that memory address.

I want to do something like:

```
address=VirtualAlloc(NULL,len+1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
dest=strncpy(address, buf, len);
```

And then I want to do this in ASM:

```
MOV EAX, dest
CALL EAX.
```

I've tried something like:

```
  __asm__("movl %eax, dest\n\t"
 "call %eax\n\t");
```

But it does not work.
How can I do it?

Comment: cast the pointer to function pointer and call it?

Comment: In AT&T syntax, `movl %eax, dest` is a store, not a load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is usually no need to use asm for this, you can simply go through a function pointer and let the compiler take care of the details.

You do need to use `__builtin___clear_cache(buf, buf+len)` after copy machine code to a buffer before you dereference a function-pointer to it, otherwise it can be [optimized away as a dead store.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741814/how-does-builtin-clear-cache-work#comment85964322_35741869).  x86 has coherent instruction caches so it doesn't compile to any extra instructions, but you still need it so the optimizer knows what's going on.

```
static inline
int func(char *dest, int len) {
    __builtin___clear_cache(dest, dest+len); // no instructions on x86 but still needed
    int ret = ((int (*)(void))dest)();   // cast to function pointer and deref
    return ret;
}
```

[compiles with GCC9.1 `-O2 -m32` to](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+func(char+*dest,+int+len)+%7B%0A++++__builtin___clear_cache(dest,+dest%2Blen)%3B+//+no+instructions+on+x86+but+still+needed%0A++++int+ret+%3D+((int+(*)(void))dest)()%3B+++//+cast+to+function+pointer+and+deref%0A++++return+ret%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-O2+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
func(char*, int):
    jmp     [DWORD PTR [esp+4]]    # tailcall
```

Also, you don't actually need to *copy* a string, you can just `mprotect` or `VirtualProtect` the page it's in to make it executable.  But if you want to make sure it does stop at the first `0` byte to test your shellcode, then sure copy it.

---

If you nevertheless insist on inline asm, you should know that gcc inline asm is a complex thing. Also, if you expect the function to return, you should really make sure it follows the calling convention, in particular it preserves the registers it should.

AT&T syntax is `op src, dst` so your `mov` was actually a store to the global symbol `dest`.

That said, here is the answer to the question as worded:

```
int ret;
__asm__ __volatile__ ("call *%0" : "=a" (ret) : "0" (dest) : "ecx", "edx", "memory");
```

Explanation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

`call *%0` = the `%0` refers to the first substitued argument, the `*` is standard `gas` syntax for indirect call

`"=a" (ret)` = output argument in `eax` register should be assigned to variable `ret` after the block

`"0" (dest)` = input argument in the same place as output argument `0` (which is `eax`) should be loaded from `dest` before the block

`"ecx", "edx"` = tell the compiler these registers may be altered by the asm block, as per normal calling convention.

`"memory"` = tell the compiler the asm block might make unspecified modifications to memory, so don't cache anything

---

Note that in x86-64 System V (Linux / OS X), it's not safe to make a function call from inline asm like this.  There's no way to declare a clobber on the red zone below RSP.

Comment: It works like magic!! Would you mind to explain this specific example within the response?? Thanks! ;)