# How does __builtin___clear_cache work?

Tags: c++, caching, built-in

Going through the gcc documentation, I stumbled into the builtin function `__builtin___clear_cache`.

> — Built-in Function: void __builtin___clear_cache (char *begin, char
>   *end) This function is used to flush the processor's instruction cache for the region of memory between begin inclusive and end exclusive.
>   Some targets require that the instruction cache be flushed, after
>   modifying memory containing code, in order to obtain deterministic
>   behavior.
>
> If the target does not require instruction cache flushes,
>   __builtin___clear_cache has no effect. Otherwise either instructions are emitted in-line to clear the instruction cache or a call to the
>   __clear_cache function in libgcc is made.

I find this interesting, but surprising. In many cases, a large number of the instructions for the current stack is stored in the L1 cache (instruction cache). So it would seem at first glance that this builtin could corrupt significantly the flow of our program, by making it wipe out the next instructions on the stack.

Does this instruction also repopulates the part of the stack that was in the L1 cache?

This seems unlikely. If it does not, then I suppose the onus is on the user to use the right `begin` and `end` arguments, so as to not corrupt our process. In practice, how could one find what the right `begin` and `end` to use?

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? What is your program actually doing?

Comment: There are no instructions on the stack.

Comment: Note that __builtin___clear_cache doesn't wipe out instructions, it flushes/clears the cache, a processor would re-populate it.

Comment: The problem is unclear, the questioner must have some misunderstanding about caches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just emitting some weird machine instruction[s] on target processors requiring them (x86 don't need that).

Think of `__builtin___clear_cache` as a "portable" (to GCC and compatible compilers) way to flush the instruction cache (e.g. in some [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library).

> In practice, how could one find what the right begin and end to use?

To be safe, I would use that on some page range (e.g. obtained with `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`....), so usually a 4Kbyte aligned memory range (multiple of 4Kbyte). Otherwise, you want some target specific trick to find the cache line width...

On Linux, you might read `/proc/cpuinfo` and use the `cache_alignment` & `cache_size` lines to get a more precise cache line size and alignment.

BTW, a code using `__builtin__clear_cache` is very likely to be (for other reasons) target machine specific, so it has or knows some machine parameters (and that should include cache size & alignment).

Comment: Turns out `__builtin___clear_cache` *is* needed on x86 as a compiler memory barrier, to make gcc realize that the "dead" stores were actually writing code, and need to happen before a cast to a function pointer.  See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236#160236 for why I wrote https://godbolt.org/g/pGXn3B, which repeats `dec eax` M times then appends a `ret`.  Without `__builtin___clear_cache` or a compiler memory barrier like `asm("":::"memory");`, the `memset` is optimized away so it's just `call` to the malloc return without storing first.

Comment: I think `__builtin___clear_cache` is supposed to work if you just use it on the exact range of bytes you wrote and now want to execute.  If it needs to know about cache-line size, it will figure it out itself, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes It looks like that's actually related to the use of `malloc` to allocate the memory, rather than to being on x86. In particular, if I replace `malloc(M+1)` with `mmap(NULL, M+1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);`, then the dead-store optimization doesn't happen even without `__builtin___clear_cache`.

Comment: @Joseph no.  Gcc knows about malloc  (private memory nothing else has a pointer to).  That enables the optimization where it can't prove it's safe with mmap.  But happening to work != totally safe and correct.

Comment: I don't think __builtin___clear_cache() has a memory barrier effect! It's not true.

Answer (score 0):

On x86, the `__builtin___clear_cache()` does nothing. (but note it's not declared as a pure function)

On aarch64, the `__builtin___clear_cache()` will be finally expanded as a function call to `__aarch64_sync_cache_range()` in libgcc. You can view the GCC code below to understand how it is implemented.

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/config/aarch64/sync-cache.c#L31

And for Clang it is here:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/clear_cache.c#L123

Comment: On x86 a call to `__builtin___clear_cache` compiles to zero asm instructions, but it does prevent dead-store elimination and similar effects which can be a correctness problem. (Especially if you allocate memory on the stack and it's executable because of `-zexecstack`, so GCC knows the array is private to this function invocation and that you're not passing a pointer to it outside of this function.) https://godbolt.org/z/5671x3MYn shows an example of a test program that fails on x86-64 without `__builtin___clear_cache`.  Your answer is useful for AArch64, but wrong for x86-64.

Comment: See also [execute binary machine code from C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18476002) and [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960721)

Comment: As I pointed out in another question, the above effect is due to that __builtin___clear_cache() is not declared as a 'pure' function, even though it's empty.

Comment: It's a builtin that fully inlines.  The compiler knows that it doesn't actually read or write anything, it just pretends that it does.