# Threads spawned by a detoured pthread_create do not execute instructions

Tags: macos, x86, pthreads, x86-64, detours

I've got a custom implementation of detours on macOS and a test application using it, which is written in C, compiled for macOS x86_64, running on an Intel i9 processor.

The implemention works fine with a multitude of functions. However, if I detour `pthread_create`, I encounter strange behaviour: threads that have been spawned via a detoured pthread_create do not execute instructions. I can step through instructions one by one but as soon as I `continue` it does not progress. There are no mutexes or synchronisation involved and the result of the function is 0 (success). The exact same application with detours turned off works fine so it's unlikely to be the culprit.

This does not happen all the time - sometimes they are fine but at other times the test applications stalls in the following state:

```
(lldb) bt all
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff7296f55e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ulock_wait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff72a325c2 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_join + 347
    frame #2: 0x0000000100001186 DetoursTestApp`main + 262
    frame #3: 0x00007fff7282ccc9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #4: 0x00007fff7282ccc9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
  thread #2
    frame #0: 0x00007fff72a2cb7c libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start
```

Relevant memory pages have the executable flag set. The detour function that intercepts the thread creation looks like this:

```
static int pthread_create_detour(pthread_t* thread,
                                 const pthread_attr_t* attr,
                                 void* (*start_routine)(void*),
                                 void* arg)
{
    detour_count++;
    pthread_fn original = (pthread_fn)detour_original(dlsym((void*)-1, "pthread_create"));
    return original(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}
```

Where `detour_original` retrieves the pointer to [original function + size of function's prologue].
Tracing through the instructions, everything seems to be working correctly and `pthread_create` terminates successfully. Tracing the application's system calls via `dtruss` does show calls to

```
bsdthread_create(0x10DB964B0, 0x0, 0x7000080DB000)               = 29646848 0
```

With what I have confirmed are the correct arguments.

This behaviour is only observed in release builds - debug works fine but the disassembly and execution of a detoured `pthread_create` and associated detours code seems to be identical in both cases.

---

#### Workarounds

I found a couple of odd workarounds for this issue that don't make much sense. Given the detour function, a number of things can be substituted into the following:

```
static int pthread_create_detour(pthread_t* thread,
                                 const pthread_attr_t* attr,
                                 void* (*start_routine)(void*),
                                 void* arg)
{
    detour_count++;
    pthread_fn original = (pthread_fn)detour_original(dlsym((void*)-1, "pthread_create"));
    <...> <== SUBSTITUTE HERE
    return original(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}
```

1. A cache flush.

```
    __asm__ __volatile__("" ::: "memory");
    _mm_clflush(real_pthread_create);
```

2. A sleep of any duration - `usleep(1)`
3. A `printf` statement.
4. A memory allocation larger than 32768 bytes, e.g. `void *data = malloc(40000);`.

#### Cache?

All of these seem to point to a stale instruction cache. However, the Intel manual states the following:

> A write to a memory location in a code segment that is currently cached in the processor causes the associated cache line (or lines) to be invalidated. This check is based on the physical address of the instruction. In addition, the P6 family and Pentium processors check whether a write to a code segment may modify an instruction that has been prefetched for execution. If the write affects a prefetched instruction, the prefetch queue is invalidated. This latter check is based on the linear address of the instruction.

What's even more interesting is that those workarounds have to be executed for every new thread created, with the execution happening on the main thread, so it's very unlikely to be the cache. I have also tried putting in cache flushes at every memory write that writes instructions but that did not help. I've also written a `memcpy` that bypasses the cache with the use of Intel's intrinsic `_mm_stream_si32` and swapped it out for every instruction memory write in my implementation without any success.

---

#### Race condition?

The next suspect in line is a race condition. However, it's not clear what would be racing as at first there are no other threads. I have put in a fibonacci sequence calculation for a randomly-generated number and that would still stall the newly-spawned threads.

---

#### The question

What is causing this issue? What other mechanisms could be responsible for this?

At this point I have run out of things to check so any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: It's not stale cache at a CPU level; we know that can't happen in practice on real hardware per the documentation you found, and from experiment:  [Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395557)

It's pehaps *compile-time* reordering of the store with the call, because compilers assume that stores don't alias code unless you tell them otherwise. (e.g. with GNU C `__builtin___clear_cache(start, end)` on a range of insns you stored to). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56213671/224132) re: writing machine code from C

Comment: Thanks, these were interesting reads. I gave `__builtin___clear_cache` a go but it did not resolve the issue. In fact, iterating through the code instruction by instruction via `lldb` shows the correct instructions being written out to memory and they also seem to be executed correctly. I must also point out that this behaviour is only observed in release builds - debug works fine but the disassembly and execution of a detoured `pthread_create` and relevant code seems to be identical in both cases.
I have also checked whether the memory pages are executable, which they are.

Comment: Is it possible to create an actual [mcve] someone else could use to reproduce this on a MacOS system?  I don't have one, but it's probably going to be hard for anyone to help you without being able to try it.  I still suspect some kind of compile-time reordering is most likely the issue, especially if optimized vs. unoptimized matters, and `asm("" ::: "memory");` fixes it.  (I'm guessing that compiler memory barrier works without an actual clflush, and that the other things like printf or malloc work because they also are non-inline function calls that are effectively compiler barriers)

Comment: Or maybe there is some kind of timing issue since you say a smaller malloc wouldn't work?  So maybe draining the store buffer on this core so your store is visible to other cores?  clflush might be slow enough to do that.  Maybe try `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` from C11 `<stdatomic.h>`.  (i.e. `mfence` or a dummy `lock`ed operation)

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I could not provide a minimal reproducible example due to the implementation being tied up with proprietary code. Fortunately, I did find a solution in the end (see answer). The thing all of the aforementioned workarounds had in common was that those particular sequences of commands would clear `r8`. I don't think it would've been possible to solve it for anyone else without me sharing the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the reason why the spawned thread was not executing instructions was that the `r8` register wasn't being cleared at the right time in the execution of `pthread_create` due to an issue with my detours implementation.

If we look at the disassembly of the function, it is split up to two parts - the "head" and the "body" that's found in an internal `_pthread_create` function. The head does two things - zeroes out `r8` and jumps to the body:

```
libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_create:
    0x7fff72a2e236 <+0>: 45 31 c0        xor    r8d, r8d
    0x7fff72a2e239 <+3>: e9 40 37 00 00  jmp    0x7fff72a3197e            ; _pthread_create

libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_create:
    0x7fff72a3197e <+0>:    55                                push   rbp
    0x7fff72a3197f <+1>:    48 89 e5                          mov    rbp, rsp
    0x7fff72a31982 <+4>:    41 57                             push   r15
    <...> // the rest of the 1409 instructions
```

My implementation would detour the internal `_pthread_create` function instead of the head containing the actual entry point which meant that the `r8` would get cleared at the wrong time (before the detour). Since the detour function would contain some could, the execution would go something like:

`pthread_create` (`r8` gets cleared) -> `_pthread_create` -> chain of jumps -> `pthread_create_detour` -> trampoline (containing the beginning of `_pthread_create`) -> `_pthread_create + 6`

Which meant that depending on the contents of the `pthread_create_detour` function the `r8` would not always end up with a 0 when it returned to the internal function.

It's not yet clear why having `r8` set to something other than 0 before `_pthread_create` would not crash but instead start up a thread in a locked up state. An important detail is that the stalled thread would have the `rflags` register set to `0x200` which should never be the case according to [Intel's manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf#page=79). This is what lead me to inspecting the CPU state more closely, leading to the answer.